# Перебор по битовой маске в Python

Tags: python, маска

Друзья, подскажите нубу, как сделать на примере Python перебор по битовой маске? Я читаю и не понимаю.

Есть десятичное число, в котором с помощью битов зашифрованы параметры:
Если первый бит равен 0, то параметр a, если первый бит равен 1, параметр b
Второй бит: если 0 то c, если 1 то d
Третий бит: если 0 то e, если 1 то f

Например в числе 5 (101) зашифрованы параметры bcf

У меня может быть какой-то словарь вида

```
parameters = {0: {0: "a", 1: "b" }, 1: {0: "c", 1: "d" }, 2: {0: "e", 1: "f" }, }
```

Какой цикл будет извлекать из десятичного числа эти параметры по битовой маске?

Answer (score 3):

```
n = ...
for k, v in parameters.items():
    k2 = 0 if n & (1 << k) == 0 else 1
    print(k, v[k2])
```

Comment: Как вариант: `print(k, v[(n>>k) & 1])`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы при такой формулировке решал вообще без какого-то словаря. Просто используем коды букв, вычисляя каждый следующий по простой формуле (начиная с 97 - кода символа `a`) и переводя этот код назад в символ. Например, так.

```
n= 5
st=''
for i in range (len(bin(n)[2:])):
   st += chr(97 + 2*i + int(bin(n)[2+i]))
print (st)
```